# Ideal design for reusing data across different environments

Tags: design, architecture, azure, development-environment

We have 3 subscriptions in our Azure management group: DEV, TEST & PROD

We use Azure Maps to get weather insights data via some Databricks jobs

In order to roll things off quickly, we replicated the setup in all three environments and all is working well

Now as a part of efficiency and cost optimisation, we want to reuse weather data acquired in one environment and eliminate the need of running the same thing in 3 environments (because weather data acquired from Azure maps is same, no matter where you call it from)

My question is: which environment do we acquire the data in?

My opinion is: We acquire the data in DEV because giving "PROD read-access to DEV" is less harmful than the other way around

Once we've worked out which environment to acquire the data in, second question is how? Two options are:

Physically copy the data from 1 environment to another
Give PROD read-access such that it reads from another environment on runtime. We wouldn't want to cross-pollinate the environments if that's a possibile. We're aware that it will cost us 3 times.
Any suggestions / recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're 90% of the way to the answer here - there are trade-offs to be made (e.g. copying data between environments vs letting one environment read from another). However, that last 10% is something only you can decide, based on your particular circumstances - there is no one best "ideal design" which applies to all of software engineering.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal would be to have some test weather data which covered all possible test scenarios for your software.

Rather than pull live data and replicate it, create your own set of weather data and mock the AzureMaps calls so they always return it.

This way your dev and test environments have a known set of data and your tests will be repeatable.

Also, if its cost considerations driving this you would probably be well served by using the same kind of setup to create a caching setup in live.

Once you have that, then you could point all the environments you want at your live Weather Api and it automatically reuses data already fetched by your live system.